# How can i get object from List

Tags: scala, playframework

I need to get an object `User(1,Nick Holland,25,None)` from the `List(Map())`, but I can't understand how

```
val a = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.toSeq.map(a => a.map(b => b))

List(Map(name -> ArrayBuffer(), age -> ArrayBuffer(), deleteItem -> ArrayBuffer(User(1,Nick Holland,25,None)), action -> ArrayBuffer(remove)))
```

Comment: Can you please explain your real problem, and what exactly you do not understand? - I mean, I doubt your list will always be of one element, what should happen if it is empty, and if there are 2+ values? - The inner maps will always have the same keys? or you are sure the key `deleteItem`  will always be? - The values will always be Seqs of User? again what should happen when there are many elements? - do you want to get the value for what?, you only want a `val` with a single element?, do you want to extract a List of all Users that satisfy a condition? - Finally, what have you tried?

Comment: Also, I do not think this has nothing to do with **Play**, apart from that your list comes from a request. You may just provide the example input _(as you already did)_ and explain the expected output. You can remove the **Play** tag and leave this as an **Scala** only problem. - BTW, I do not use **Play***, but this `toSeq.map(a => a.map(b => b))` seems unnecessary to me, at least the `map`s are only the _identity_, not sure if the `toSeq` is also redundant.

Comment: The problem is this:
I'm trying to program buttons using Forms (import play.api.data.Form, play.api.data.Forms._)
There are two buttons "Add" and "Delete". For the "Add" button
input must be filled. For the "Delete" is not critical.
And when you click the "Delete" button, a POST request is sent with empty fields.
age and name. 
`name -> ArrayBuffer (), age -> ArrayBuffer ().`
Respectively 
`val formData: BasicForm = BasicForm.form.bindFromRequest.get` 
so it is impossible to get the contents of the form because Empty age and name give None.

Comment: Then, why you are using a List? If there will be always one element?, If the types of the field are different, why don't you use a `case class` _(with **Optional** fields)_ instead of a `Map`?  - As I said before, I do not use play, so I am not 100% sure. But I think you are modeling bad your request input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
case class User(i: Int, str: String, i1: Int, opt: Option[String])
val l = List(Map("name" -> ArrayBuffer(), "age" -> ArrayBuffer(), "deleteItem" -> ArrayBuffer(User(1,"Nick Holland",25,None)), "action" -> ArrayBuffer("remove")))
l.head.apply("deleteItem").head //User(1,Nick Holland,25,None)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot.

Comment: sorry for arrogance, but how to get out of this String age and name (1 and Nick Holland) and put it in variable's: `val id: Int = 1 val name: String ="Nick Holland"`

Comment: `val user = l.head.apply("deleteItem").head` `val id: Int = user.i` `val name: String = user.str` (use your parameter names instead of my `i`, `str`, ...)

Comment: If it was `case class User(id: Int, name: String, ...)` then `val id: Int = user.id` `val name: String = user.name` ...